# JScript Delete Operator

Tags: c#, jscript

Question:

Can someone list me some operators that resemble the delete operator in terms of syntax?

Background:

I am working on a large application and have to somehow create a list and fill this list with certain attributes. This application will already do this for some operators, so I need to find one that is similar to the delete so that I can look at what they store in the list.

Additional:

This is a sample of a method I'm trying to recreate (though this is from a 'print' it may not work for the delete, hence why I need an operand similar to delete so I can look at their method):

```
internal override List<Object> Unparse() {
  List<Object> tokens = new List<Object>();
  tokens.Add(JSToken.Identifier);
  tokens.Add("print");
  bool enclosedInParen = false;
  List<Object> argItems = operand.Unparse();
  enclosedInParen = JSScannerAst.EnclosedInParen(argItems);
  if (!enclosedInParen) {
    tokens.Add(JSToken.LeftParen);
  }
  tokens.AddRange(argItems);
  if (!enclosedInParen) {
    tokens.Add(JSToken.RightParen);
  }
  //tokens.Add(JSToken.Semicolon);
  return tokens;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean similar to the delete operator? You need to fill a list based off the usage of the `delete` operator in JScript? Can you provide a sample to further explain your needs perhaps?

Comment: added additional info :)

Comment: What is this code doing?  It's really not clear.  Unparse() is creating parse tokens?

Comment: This code is awful, really annoying to work on lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer:
http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~bartlett/jsops.html

This link shows many different operators and delete was grouped under 'Special Operators'.

I was then able to find an Unparse method for 'this' and use that same code for the delete unparse method.